Is Google Auth Provider is Included in Supbase Third Party Auth
I want to use supabase in my next project when I see the pricing structure, 50,000 MAU is free, but I also see third party auth is only 50, and I will try to implement Google Auth with the help of supbase.
Is Google Auth included in the supbase third party Auth?
in simple term how many google auth MAU should Supbase offer in free tier
